# Angular AOT compilation error "cannot determine module for class Component''

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, aot, angular-aot

I have an Angular (4.3.2) application on which I want to perform an AOT build. App was created using `@angular/cli`. I have two components scaffolded with `ng generate` and a module in which both are included as a declaration:

```
import {PrivateComponent} from './private.component/private.component';

NgModule({
   imports: [
      // other imports
      PrivateRoutingModule
   ],
   declarations: [
      ...some other components, 
      PrivateComponent, 
      AppTopBarComponent
   ]
   // other stuff 
}) 
export class PrivateModule {}
```

Private component is also used in the module's routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: PrivateComponent, children: // other components}
] 

@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)] // this is the Angular built-in router module
})
export class PrivateRoutingModule {}
```

Notice how the routing was defined in another module and imported into `PrivateModule`
The `AppTopBarComponent` is used inside the `PrivateComponent's` template. So both are used and declared. But when I use `"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json` (I am on Windows 10), I get this error message:
`Cannot determine the module for class PrivateComponent in (path-to-project)/src/app/pages/private/private.component/private.component.ts! Add PrivateComponent to the NgModule to fix it.`
`Cannot determine the module for class AppTopBarComponent in (path-to-project)/src/app/pages/private/app.topbar.component.ts! Add AppTopBarComponent to the NgModule to fix it.`. My `tsconfig-aot.json` file is exactly the same as is in the [Angular AOT build guide](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler).

Comment: It is worth mentioning I encountered several questions on the matter, but the problem was mostly for the unused components. Mine are actually used.

Comment: You forgot to add PrivateComponent  in import import {PrivateComponent} from './private.component/private.component';

Comment: @Vega my bad, I just missed it whilst copy-pasting. It is actually present in the source code

Comment: The first @ for NgModule too ?:)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have actually found a solution. The problem was that `PrivateComponent` was imported in another file, but not used, just like this:

```
import { PrivateComponent } from '../private/private.component'; // not used anywhere
```

Apparently `ngc` tries to link everything and is confused by an unused import

Comment: Also make sure the import path case matches the actual file path case.

Answer (score 34):

#### Make sure you don't accidentally have two files declaring the same component

This often happens to me if I'm in the wrong directory when I run `ng g c`, and don't immediately delete the wrong generated file.

> ERROR in : Cannot determine the module for class
>   FeatureBoxGroupComponent in
>   S:/.../src/app/common-widgets/feature-widgets/feature-box-group/feature-box-group.component.ts!
>   Add FeatureBoxGroupComponent to the NgModule to fix it.

In this example I had `FeatureBoxGroupComponent` defined in two places:

```
src\app\common-widgets\feature-widgets\feature-box-group\feature-box-group.component.ts

src\app\feature-widgets\feature-box-group\feature-box-group.component.ts
```

Of course the error message is telling me the exact file it has a problem with - but it's easy to glance over that.

Just do a find in files for the component name to see everywhere it's referenced and make sure it's only defined once.

Comment: In my case I must have copied and dragged the folder in error

Comment: Thanks this helped me figure it out! I was copying new build files manually to my `node_modules` in another project for testing and apparently just needed to delete all of old ones first.

Comment: Angular 9 is supposed to have improved this error message :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved this problem, assuming you are using `VScode`.

1. Close all the open tabs.
2. Stop `ng serve`
3. Move indicated component folders to some other location through `VScode`.
4. If tabs open after moving, close them and save the changes while closing (Due to path 
   change).
5. It should now compile when you run `ng build` with `--aot`

If you like, you can do the same process to move folders back to original locations.

Also, after I fixed the problem checked the `git diff` and realized that the problem was the casing. I changed the folder names to upper case but that did not get updated in the path.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it disappeared when I used `ng build` instead of `ng build --prod`.

Apparently I had two modules that I was not using but had not deleted from the app folder. They were not declared in the app.module.ts folder either.

As per the documentation the `--prod` flag causes the compiler to carry out some dead code elimination as well.